# How can I convert a long format dataframe into a wide format in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I'm working on PySpark and I have long format dataframe like this:

| KPI | GROUP | TIME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | A | Before | 100 |
| Sales | A | After | 135 |
| Sales | B | Before | 90 |
| Sales | B | After | 98 |
| Revenue | A | Before | 10 |
| Revenue | A | After | 12 |
| Revenue | B | Before | 5 |
| Revenue | B | After | 8 |

And what I expect to have is something like this:

| KPI | GROUP | BEFORE | AFTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | A | 100 | 135 |
| Sales | B | 90 | 98 |
| Revenue | A | 10 | 12 |
| Revenue | B | 5 | 8 |

Answer (score 3):

Just pivot

```
df1.groupBy('KPI'   ,'GROUP').pivot('TIME').agg(first('VALUE')).show()
```